# Converter um ArrayList<String> em um String[]

Tags: java, android, string, arraylist

Eu preciso passar os valores que estão em minha `ArrayList<String>` para uma `String[]` pois preciso fazer um `setInputData("INPUT",input)`.

Ou seja, quero converter a seguinte `ArrayList<String>` com os demais valores para um `String[]`:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("NOME 1");
list.add("NOME 2");
list.add("NOME 3");
```

Converter para:

```
String[] input = new String[0]
```

Estou tentando algumas coisas, mas estou com medo de estar fazendo da forma errada.

Eu tentei isso:

```
String[] input = list.toArray(new String[0]);
```

Mas não sei se está certo porque minha dúvida é qual a necessidade de colocar o número 0 entre `[0]` no `new String[0]` e se, fazendo desta forma, será que a conversão vai ficar deste jeito: `input = {null,"Nome 1","Nome 2","Nome 3"}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na verdade `input = list.toArray(new String[0])` funciona sem problemas, só tem um detalhe.

Segundo a [documentação](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray(T[])), o método `toArray` verifica se a lista cabe no array indicado, e caso não caiba, ela aloca **outro** array com o tamanho necessário:

> *If the list fits in the specified array, it is returned therein. Otherwise, **a new array is allocated** with the runtime type of the specified array and the size of this list*

Em tradução livre:

> Se a lista couber no array, é retornada neste. Caso contrário, **um novo array é alocado**, com o mesmo tipo do array informado, e com o tamanho desta lista.

Isso tem uma pequena implicação. Se o array tiver o tamanho igual ao da lista, os elementos são copiados diretamente nele, então eu nem preciso pegar o retorno de `toArray`:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("NOME 1");
list.add("NOME 2");
list.add("NOME 3");
String[] input = new String[list.size()];

// array tem o tamanho da lista, ele é modificado dentro do método
list.toArray(input);
for (String s : input) {
    System.out.println(s); // imprime os 3 nomes
}
```

Repare que eu não atribuí o retorno de `toArray` para nenhuma variável. Como o array possui tamanho suficiente para ter todos os elementos da lista, estes são copiados diretamente para o array. Este código imprime os 3 nomes:

```
NOME 1
NOME 2
NOME 3
```

---

Mas se o array não tiver tamanho suficiente, um novo array é alocado e retornado. Já o array que eu passei como argumento para `toArray` não é modificado:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("NOME 1");
list.add("NOME 2");
list.add("NOME 3");
String[] input = new String[0];
list.toArray(input);
for (String s : input) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Neste caso, o array `input` não tem tamanho suficiente para conter todos os elementos da lista, então `toArray` aloca **outro** array com o tamanho adequado e o retorna. Mas eu não atribuí este retorno em nenhuma variável, e o array `input` continua vazio. Por isso este código não imprime nada.

Para que o código acima funcione corretamente, eu teria que fazer `input = list.toArray(input)`.

---

Por fim, se o array tiver um tamanho maior que o da lista, os elementos excedentes serão nulos:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("NOME 1");
list.add("NOME 2");
list.add("NOME 3");
String[] input = new String[list.size() + 10];
list.toArray(input);
for (String s : input) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Neste caso, o array tem um tamanho maior que a lista, e a saída é:

```
NOME 1
NOME 2
NOME 3
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
```

E neste caso, mesmo se eu fizer `input = list.toArray(input)`, a saída também é a mesma. Afinal, é o que está descrito na documentação: se a lista cabe no array, os elementos são copiados diretamente para este. Então neste caso o array retornado é o mesmo que foi passado para `toArray`, já que ele tem espaço de sobra para conter todos os elementos da lista.

---

Podemos ainda fazer outro teste, para confirmar se outro array é alocado ou não, pegando o retorno de `toArray` e comparando com o array original, para saber se de fato está sendo retornado outro array ou o mesmo:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("NOME 1");
list.add("NOME 2");
list.add("NOME 3");

String[] input = new String[0];
String[] other = list.toArray(input);
System.out.println(other == input);
```

Neste caso, o código imprime `false`, pois como `input` não tem tamanho suficiente para ter todos os elementos da lista, `toArray` aloca outro array (que é retornado e atribuído na variável `other`).

Mas se o tamanho de `input` for `list.size()` (ou qualquer valor maior que isso), aí o código imprime `true`, pois como agora o array tem espaço para todos os elementos da lista, não é alocado um novo array.

---

Resumindo, se você fizer qualquer uma das alternativas abaixo:

```
String[] input = list.toArray(new String[0]);
String[] input = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
```

Ambas funcionam. A diferença é que a primeira vai criar 2 arrays: um com tamanho zero, e outro que é alocado internamente por `toArray`, já que o array de tamanho zero não tem espaço para os elementos da lista (exceto se a lista for vazia, [pois aí retorna o mesmo array](https://ideone.com/DbSTHI)). Já a segunda alternativa só vai alocar um array e retorná-lo.

Comment: Poxa muito bem explicado..... Valeu mesmo! Esse conhecimento carregarei comigo para sempre. Você abardou bem o assunto e foi muito mais além.... agradeço muito por dividir seu conhecimento comigo e com a comunidade....

Answer (score 2):

Amigo, você não esta conseguindo pois não esta passando o tamanho do List para seu Array, você esta criando o Array com tamanho 0.
Mude seu código de:

```
String[] input = list.toArray(new String[0]);
```

para

```
String[] input = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
```

Comment: Então desta forma, todos os valores que estão contido no ArrayList<String> passa para o String[] né?

Comment: @Andréalas isso mesmo, todos os valores do seu List (ArrayList<String>) vão para o array (String[])

Comment: Poxa muito obrigado.... Valeu mesmo pela ajuda!!

Comment: @Andréalas Mas se fizer `list.toArray(new String[0])` também funciona, [veja](https://ideone.com/gW47wY). No caso, se vc passa um array com tamanho zero, internamente o método `toArray` aloca outro com o tamanho necessário, conforme descrito na [documentação](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray(T[]))

Comment: @Andréalas De qualquer forma, coloquei uma resposta detalhando melhor esse comportamento